# laravel mysql join 4 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 3 MySQL tables as bellow

```
products
id,image,sku


product_attachment
id,our_sku,item_sku

order
id,date,status

order_details
id,price,sku,qty
```

I am trying to make MYSQL join in the Larvel7 application as bellow.

I will get order_details fields plus image from product table

1. I want to get order_details of orders whos status is 'Active' in the order table
2. In order detail, I will check the SKU with product_attachment table and get our_sku
3. now I will check our_sku of product_attachment with SKU of product table and get image

bellow is my code but it's getting each record multiple times.

```
$data = DB::table('order')
          ->select(['order.*','products.image','product_attachment.our_sku','order_details.sku','order_details.quantity','order_details.price'])
          ->leftJoin('order_details', 'order.id', '=', 'order_details.id')
          ->leftJoin('product_attachment', 'order_details.sku', '=', 'product_attachment.item_sku')
          ->leftJoin('products', 'product_attachment.our_sku', '=', 'products.sku')
          ->where(['order.status'=>'Active'])
          ->get();
```

Comment: how are those tables related?

Comment: no relation model

Comment: when I check your join code, it's so wired. I think, if possible, you have to redesign your tables with foreign key so that they are related each other based on keys.

Comment: Joint is now between 
(order , order_details) =>id
order_details =>sku & product_attachment=>item_sku
product_attachment =>our_sku & products=>sku

how can I get what I want ?